# Incrementing primitive wrapper class passed as a parameter to a method which has no affect on invoker

Tags: eclipse, java-8, integer, pass-by-reference, wrapper

I'm writing the Java SE 8 app on Eclipse IDE. The issue that I came across is following.

```
private Object[][] adjustIndexTaskValueAdded(int size){
        Integer adjustingIndex = 0;
        Object[][] tasksDisplay = new Object[size][taskValues[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {                        
            tasksDisplay[i][0] = taskValues[i][0];//phase colour
            tasksDisplay[i][1] = identifyNextRowIDTaskTable(adjustingIndex, i);// the index
        }
       return tasksDisplay;
 }
```

So, I've got `adjustingIndex` **Integer wrapper** class which I pass to the `identifyNextRowIDTaskTable()` method. So that the local var can store the value which gets modified at the child method.

```
private String identifyNextRowIDTaskTable(Integer adjustingIndex, int currentRowID){
       if(UtilityOperations.isPhaseRow(phaseColourCurrent)){//it's a phase row
            adjustingIndex++;
            return "";
        }
        else{//it's a task row
            int displayID = tableID - adjustingIndex;
            adjustingIndex = 0;
            return String.valueOf(displayID);           
        }   
}
```

The above methods displays the method which modifies the **Integer wrapper** class which I pass to.
Now when I run the app, the new value is not reflected at the invoker method. It appears that value changes/adjusts at the child method, but the parent method does not see the changes. In the end, the outcome becomes erroneous.

The displayed source-code is simplified...

So, what the problem is?
I pass reference type var, and it is not a recursive operation.
I could use object's state to store the value instead, of-course. Yet, I want to understand the current pitfall.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

```
adjustingIndex++;
```

This is unboxing the value from the `Integer` to get an `int` and incrementing that value, this is equivalent to:

```
int tmp = adjustingIndex.intValue();
tmp++;
adjustingIndex = Integer.valueOf(tmp);
```

This resets the **parameter** `adjustingIndex` to be a reference to a new Integer, it does not change the value of the `adjustingIndex` variable in the calling method - that is a separate reference.

Again consider:

```
adjustingIndex = 0;
```

Again this resets the parameter `adjustingIndex` to be a reference to a new Integer, it does not change the value of the `adjustingIndex` variable in the calling method.

One alternative would be to use `AtomicInteger`

```
AtomicInteger adjustingIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

increment with

```
adjustingIndex.incrementAndGet();
```

set back to zero with

```
adjustingIndex.set(0);
```

`AtomicInteger` has methods to change the value of the integer it contains, in contrast `Integer` is immutable and its value can't be changed.